# readymade workspace of 3rd party libraries (c++)

Tags: libraries, workspace

I work at a startup. Recently, we planned to build up a workspace so that our team can work together efficiently by sharing and we can have multiple projects inside our workspace.

We are integrating a number of 3rdparty libraries[with code] in our cross platform workspace. Wondering if we could get some existing project workspace which already has large number of 3rdparty libraries and useful code snippets integrated.

We found Boost and GraphicsMagick to be very good for our purpose though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using tools to autogenerate your workspace/solution files so that you can load them up in your IDE and have the proper linker and include paths already set.

At my company, we started using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), which can generate solution files for Microsoft Visual Studio, Eclipse with CDT, KDevelop3, code::blocks, and a variety Makefiles.

An alternative is [Scons](http://www.scons.org) which can perform the same tasks, but I do not know what kind of files they generate other than Visual Studio .sln files.

Makes it less painful when you have to start changing software versions, and you do not have to share a workspace configuration that could be dependent on set paths on a user's machine.